# extracting thumbnail from a content

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm using ckeditor to generate content, and I'm trying to get a thumbnail of image if image got generated.
In my models.py

```
from goose import Goose

    class Post(models.Model):
        content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')


        def thumbnail(self):
            g = Goose()
            thumbnail = g.extract(content=self.content)
            return thumbnail
```

I thought I would extract image with python goose extractor, I thought this is the right way, but soon realized I might be approaching it wrong. 
In my html file,

```
{{ post.content|safe }}

{{ post.thumbnail }}
```

content is generated like above, but I don't get any thumbnail. Am I approaching it wrong?is there any other way I can extract the image from the content that's made by user by wysiwyg editor

Edit:

```
def thumbnail(self, content):
    g = Goose()
    thumbnail = g.extract(content=self.content).top_image.src
    return thumbnail
```

In html

```
       <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Goose.extract()` returns an article object, not a thumbnail. Try:

```
thumbnail = g.extract(raw_html=self.content).top_image.src
```

this will return an URL for the main image of the article. You can then use it in your templates like this:

```
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}">
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer sounds very reasonable to me but I get nothing again. I'll upload what I had put, if you can take a look at it, thank youvery much

Comment: It looks like the initialization argument should be `raw_html` instead of `content`. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but nothing shows up again...I just simply switched thumbanil=.. line from the above, edited question.

Comment: It's hard to see what I'm doing wrong since I don't get any error, it just simply won't show up, I have put post.thumbnail under {{post.content|safe}}

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this exact issue and eventually gave up on the Python implementation of goose. This achieves the same thing using BeautifulSoup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Post(models.Model):
  body = RichTextUploadingField()
  ...
  def thumbnail(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.body, features="lxml")
        embedded_imgs = soup.findAll('img')
        # if post author embedded any images into post, use first
        post_thumbnail = embedded_imgs[0].get(
            'src') if len(embedded_imgs) > 0 else None
        return post_thumbnail
```

Would probably be smarter to target an image with a specific ID e.g. #main-img (author can set this through ckeditor interface under Image Properties -> Advanced).